# How do I get data from a RESTful API JSON response in React?

Tags: json, reactjs, api, highcharts

I'm doing a small learning project using React and Highcharts. I was able to get the data formatted correctly using python, writing it to a text file, and manually copying it statically to the Highcharts table in my React file, but now I'm trying to make a function to get it dynamically using an API.

The chart definition for the data is setup like this:

```
series:
            [
                { showInNavigator: true, name: 'Domain', data: [getTritData(region='10000043')]},
                { showInNavigator: true, name: 'Heimatar', data: [getTritData(region='10000030')]},
                { showInNavigator: true, name: 'Metropolis', data: [getTritData(region='10000042')]},
                { showInNavigator: true, name: 'Sinq Laison', data: [getTritData(region='10000032')]},
            ],
```

I know I'm way off course, but my getTritData(region) function is setup like:

```
let data;
data.average = [];
data.date = [];

export function getTritData(region){

    let seriesData = [];
    const response = fetch('https://esi.evetech.net/latest/markets/' + region +
        '/history/?datasource=tranquility&type_id=34');
    data = JSON.parse(response);

    seriesData = data.map('{x: ' + data.date + ', y: ' + data.average + '}, ')
        //figure out how to append strResp to seriesData[]

    return seriesData
}
```

Here is what the JSON response looks like:

```
{'average': 6.19, 'date': '2020-02-01', 'highest': 6.34, 'lowest': 5.81, 'order_count': 614, 'volume': 1217418853}, {'average': 6.19, 'date': '2020-02-01', 'highest': 6.34, 'lowest': 5.81, 'order_count': 614, 'volume': 1217418853},...
```

I'm super new to Javascript, so that is likely the issue, but what I'm trying to do is parse the JSON response from the API to what the Highcharts table uses, which needs to look like:

```
{ x: 1234567890123, y: 6.5 }, { x: 1234567890123, y: 6.5 }, { x: 1234567890123, y: 6.5 },...
```

Where x is the UTC-Epoch date, and y is the value. In the JSON response these attributes are 'date' and 'average' respectively.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that'd be great! My google-fu is apparently weak for this topic.

For anyone that's curious, I was able to get what I needed from the response by copy/pasting from the text file using the python below:

```
import json
import requests
import datetime

domain = 10000043
heimatar = 10000030
metropolis = 10000042
sinq = 10000032

v1 = 'Domain'
v2 = 'Heimatar'
v3 = 'Metropolis'
v4 = 'Sinq Laison'

region = [domain, heimatar, metropolis, sinq]
region_names = [v1, v2, v3, v4]
q = 0


def unix_time_millis(date_parsed):
    epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
    return (date_parsed - epoch).total_seconds() * 1000


while q < len(region):
    r = requests.get(
        'https://esi.evetech.net/latest/markets/' + str(region[q]) + '/history/?datasource=tranquility&type_id=34')

    load_data = json.loads(r.text)

    i = 0

    with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.writelines('{ name: ' + '\'' + region_names[q] + '\'' + ', data: [')
        while i < len(load_data):
            date_parse = datetime.datetime.strptime(load_data[i]['date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
            date_converted = unix_time_millis(date_parse)
            if i == len(load_data) - 1:
                f.write('{x: ' + str(date_converted).split(".0")[0] + ', ' + 'y: ' + str(load_data[i]['average']) + '}')
            else:
                f.write('{x: ' + str(date_converted).split(".0")[0] + ', ' + 'y: ' + str(load_data[i]['average']) + '}, ')
            i = i + 1
        f.writelines(']},' + '\n')
    q = q + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `fetch` is asynchronous, it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you need to wait for it before parsing a json.

```
export function getTritData(region) {
  return fetch(
    "https://esi.evetech.net/latest/markets/" +
      region +
      "/history/?datasource=tranquility&type_id=34"
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      return data.map((dataEl) => ({
        x: new Date(dataEl.date).getTime(),
        y: dataEl.average
      }));
    });
}
```

The next thing is that how you want to handle a chart during fetching. You have two options:

- show the whole chart after data is received
- display a chart without data first and update it after data is received (below code)

---

```
const App = () => {
  const isMounted = useRef(true);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    ...,
    series: [...]
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([
      getTritData("10000043"),
      getTritData("10000030"),
      getTritData("10000042"),
      getTritData("10000032")
    ])
      .then((responses) => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setOptions({
            series: responses.map((res) => ({ data: res }))
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.message);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // componentWillUnmount
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />;
};
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-zrn14?file=/demo.jsx

Comment: Thanks! I made a lot of progress last night in that I got the data to show in the console, but using that data that’s being written to the console is the next step. Once I get home from work I’ll look over what you wrote and try some implementation. I think the piece of how the chart is being handled is the missing piece of the puzzle. Thanks for the response!